# E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache

Tags: java, android

Please assist in the below error that I am getting when trying to run my app. my app used to work fine now its showing this error and a white screen.

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced
>   from method
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache

Comment: Please add more details to the question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't added Support library for ArrayMap to use it. Just add this code as shown below to your dependencies in app\build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.1'
}
```